# Show issues instead work items in Sprint's taskboard

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

I have a azure boards project with simple flow.

We only use Epics / Issues, almost never work-items for sake of simplicity.

Can I customize the Sprint Taskboard (or create new board), so that it will show Issues in the state columns instead workitems?

[image]

Comment: No you can't. I recommend you just use the big kanban board instead. If needed add a column for Sprint Backlog & Doing and use that instead of the Sprint Backlog.

Comment: Is it possible to convert simple workflow to kanban?

Comment: Just click ln "Boards" two steps above "Sprints" under the Boards Hub.

Comment: Ah, I thought kanban is a workflow. Well, that answers is, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize the Product backlog Board to do exactly what you want. In which case you could completely ignore the "Sprints":

[image]

If needed add additional columns:

[image]

To end up with something like this:
[image]

Comment: By creating an inherited process you can probably even auto-assign the current sprint every time you drag something to Doing... But that's besides the point.

Answer (score 2):

You may create a child process based on Agile: [Create and manage inherited processes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/manage-process?view=azure-devops) and assign your project to it.

After that, you may assign Issue to any backlog level... as example:

1. open the task backlog level:

[image]

2. Add issue to the task level:

[image]

3. Use it in the sprint:

[image]